# Executing code after exception is thrown

Tags: java

So I have a bit of situation here with my design and was wondering whether I could
get some feedback.

```
public class Class1 {
    public void eatFish(){}
}

public class Class2 {
    public void eatBacon(){
        // some nasty code here to cause an exception
    }
}

public class Class3 {
    public void eatFruit(){}
}

public InvokeAllClasses() {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        Class2 c2 = new Class2();
        Class3 c3 = new Class3();

        c1.eatFish();
        c2.eatBacon();
        c3.eatFruit();
    }
}
```

See the problem here in InvokeAllClasses is that, because `c2.eatBacon();`
blows up, `c3.eatFish()` would not be executed. Is there a way to still execute
`c3` although `c2` blew up?

## Update

After thinking more about, I guess I could wrap each call in a `try...catch` block but that is just messy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the `try`...`catch` in the method defintion:

```
public void eatBacon(){
    try{
        // some nasty code here to cause an exception
    } catch(Exception e){
        //do something
    }
}
```

This won't look as bad as putting it when you call the method.  If you know where exactly in the code the exception could be happening, then only surround those statements.

Comment: Like the approach of putting it in the source of the exception

Comment: Swallowing all exceptions at source might not be a good idea, unless none of the process calling these methods will ever care about exceptions.

Comment: @plalx Since there isn't more details about the nasty code and the exception, I went for the most clean looking and readable solution that was still ok.

Comment: @plalx in my case the each method is independent of the other so it is safe to catch the exception at the source

Comment: @tawheed I think I still prefer the approach I suggested. It keeps things DRY in every methods and gives you the flexibility of handling exceptions in other processes if you want. This approach is still fine however.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the exceptions within the methods themselves so they aren't thrown back up to the calling method, but other than try/catch/finally blocks, there isn't a good practice way to ignore exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are sure that you will never have to handle any exceptions thrown by those methods, it might be better to avoid swallowing all of them at the source.

It's been a while since I wrote Java code and I could not try and compile it, but the idea is to create an object which has the responsability to execute tasks and swallow any exceptions.

It may look like:

```
public class SilentExecutor {
    List<Runnable> tasks;

    public SilentExecutor(List<Runnable) tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks == null? new List<Runnable>() : tasks;
    }

    public void execute() {
        for (Runnable task : this.tasks) silentlyExecute(task);
    }

    private void silentlyExecute(Runnable task) {
        try { task.run(); }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Then your code could be something like:

```
new SilentExecutor(Arrays.asList(
    () -> { c1.eatFish(); },
    () -> { c2.eatBacon(); },
    () - > { c3.eatFruit(); }
)).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just catch the exception and move on? I honestly don't think it will be messy.

Answer (score 0):

Make your method to throw an exception.

```
public InvokeAllClasses() throws Exception {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class1 c1 = new Class1();
    Class2 c2 = new Class2();
    Class3 c3 = new Class3();

    try{
        c1.eatFish();
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Oh noes! There was something wrong!!!")}
    finally{
        c2.eatBacon();
        c3.eatFruit();  
    }

}
```

As you can see. The "finally" statement will force your code to perform no matter if the statement inside the try fails or throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you could take.  The first option is to ignore the exceptions completely.

```
try {
  c1.eatFish();
} catch(Exception e) {//Ignore}
try {
  c2.eatBacon();
} catch(Exception e) {//Ignore}
try {
  c3.eatFruit();
} catch(Exception e) {//Ignore}
```

If you want the exception to be thrown in the end, you can put the result into a variable and then `throw` it at the end or use the `finally` clause.

```
try {
  c1.eatFish();
finally {
  try {
     c2.eatBacon();
  } finally {
     c3.eatFruit();
  }
}
```

If you are looking for something more readable, you could wrap the method calls.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        Class2 c2 = new Class2();
        Class3 c3 = new Class3();

        callEatFishIgnoringException(c1);
        callEatBaconIgnoringException(c2);
        callEatFruitIgnoringException(c3);
    }

    private static void callEatFishIgnoringException(Class1 c1) {
      try {c1.eatFish()} catch (Exception e) {//Ignore}
    } 

    private static void callEatBaconIgnoringException(Class2 c2) {
      try {c2.eatBacon()} catch (Exception e) {//Ignore}
    } 

    private static void callEatFruitIgnoringException(Class3 c3) {
      try {c3.eatFruit()} catch (Exception e) {//Ignore}
    }
```

Comment: Maybe so, but if you have an exception you have to handle it or use a finally clause to execute code after the exception is thrown.  Unless you can change the methods being called not to throw exceptions.  I'm not sure of your use case.  Alternatively you can wrap the method calls so it's more readable.  I'll add to answer.